# how to add days in current date

Tags: php, phpunit

```
echo "No of days:";
$var1 = file_get_contents('path to file');
echo $var1;
$var2= "-".$var1." days";  // var2= -2 days

$today = date("M d, Y");
echo $today;
$NewDate=Date(strtotime($var2));
echo date('M d, Y', $NewDate);
```

Error:Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long,

Comment: What do you see for `echo $var1;`

Comment: file contains only  2

Comment: Your code seems correct . Not sure why its not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var2= $var1." days ago";
```

Comment: Are you shure that this file contains exactly one line with "2" in ti? Try `trim($var1)." days ago";` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = file_get_contents('path to file');
echo date('M d Y',strtotime("-$var days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```
    $date = new DateTime(date("M d, Y"));
    $todayPlusTwoDays = $date->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
```

If $var1 holds the amount of days to add, simply:

```
    $todayPlusTwoDays = $date->add(new DateInterval('P'. $var1 .'D'));
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P2 D)'

Comment: Make sure you trim the value returned from the file. Also, it would be good to know which PHP are you targeting.

Answer (score 0):

From me

Remove this

```
$today = date("M d, Y");
echo $today;
```

You are not using it anyway.